# Regex to remove Key and value from JSON

Tags: java, json, regex

I have a JSON like below:

```
{"queueNumber": "123","UserId":[12,12,34],"cur":[{"objectName":"test","uniqueNumber":"123456"}]}
```

I want to remove the key-value pairs if it matches a given field.

I tried with the below regex but it adds a comma at the end which raises an exception at runtime while reading this JSON again.

```
"((queueNumber|name|uniqueNumber)[0-9]*)":(\s*)?((".*?")|(\d+.\d+)|(\w+))[,]?
```

current output:

```
{"UserId":[12,12,34],"cur":[{"objectName":"test",}]}
```

Expected output:

```
{"UserId":[12,12,34],"cur":[{"objectName":"test"}]}
```

How to remove K,V pairs without that extra comma at the end?

Comment: Why not use a JSON parser? you didn't include the language this is for but I'm sure whatever you use has a JSON parser.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast I am using a simple java program to pattern match and replace the string from the JSON.

Comment: Does this java program comes with a json parser? check the docs for it.

Comment: JSON can't be parsed reliably with a regexp. It's difficult to handle escaped quotes, balanced brackets, etc.

Comment: Match regex doesn't add characters, in our current output it's there because it's placed before the key:value you remove. Place the `[,]?` to the start so it's removed at the right location

Comment: @Randommm, this will work for this exact case, but will produce undesired outcome if one of listed fields is not first or last field of corresponding object. Consider [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/30TPg4/1)

Comment: @markalex Sorry worded that wrong, "move the `[,]/`"*

Answer (score 1):

I second the comments, that you should probably use a JSON parser library for java. For the sake of completeness I developed both approaches:

## regex approach

We need to consider the following cases:

1. key-value-pair is alone: `{"queueNumber": "123"}`
2. key-value-pair is at the beginning: `{"queueNumber": "123","asdf": "1",...}`
3. key-value-pair is in the middle: `{,"asdf1": "1","queueNumber": "123","asdf2": "1",...}`
4. key-value-pair is at the end: `{...,"asdf1": "1","queueNumber": "123"}`

The difficulty is to not to remove too many commas. We can categorize the cases in two classes:

1. the key-value-pair starts with a comma
2. the key-value-pair doesn't start with a comma, but may(!) end with a comma
   "may end with a comma" could be considered a sub-class

If either of these classes is true, we have a full match.

Regex for class 1: `,\s*"(queueNumber|name|uniqueNumber)\d*":\s*("[^"]*?"|\d+.\d+|\w+)` 
Regex for class 2: `"(queueNumber|name|uniqueNumber)\d*":\s*("[^"]*?"|\d+.\d+|\w+)(\s*,)?`

**Full Regex (see [this link](https://regex101.com/r/VLX1ES/1)):**
`(,\s*"(queueNumber|name|uniqueNumber)\d*":\s*("[^"]*?"|\d+.\d+|\w+))|("(queueNumber|name|uniqueNumber)\d*":\s*("[^"]*?"|\d+.\d+|\w+)(\s*,)?)`

**Explanation:**

- `,\s*` - matches a comma followed by any whitespace 0 - unlimited times
- `"` - match the literal char `"`
- `(queueNumber|name|uniqueNumber)\d*` - matches either `queueNumber`, `name` or `uniqueNumber`, followed by optional numbers
- `":\s*` - literal `":` followed by optional whitespaces
- `("[^"]*?"|\d+.\d+|\w+)` - matches either anything inside of quotation marks, a decimal digit or a word 
  ** `[^"]*?` - lazy match of any string, that does not contain `"` ([^abc]-creates a word class with all chars, that are not `a`, `b` or `c`). Lazy means, the regex tries to match the least amount of chars possible.
- `(.a.)|(.b.)` matches either the first(`a`) or the second(`b`) regex. If the first regex matched, the second regex is ignored.
- `(\s*,)?` optionally matches optional white spaces followed by a comma 
  ** `?` - means 0 to 1 matches

**Improvements to your regex approach:**

- you didn't need so many groups `(...)`. Grouping is only necessary for replacing or to apply a quantifier or other logic to a sub-regex. The boolean OR operator is not applied to single chars/matchers, but to the whole connected chars then come before and follow after.
- `\d` is the same as `[0-9]`
- `[,]?` can be simplified to `,?`
- `(\s*)?` can be simplified to `\s*` → the `*` already means 0-infinity matches. So there is no need to make this part optional with the `?` quantifier
- Your approach to match the value-part (`(".*?"|\d+.\d+|\w+)`) can get out of hand, because of the part `.*?`. Your rightfully made it a lazy match. But if the regex doesn't find something in the way you intended to, the laziness will not stop it to go on as far as possible to get at least one match. A better approach is to replace the `.`-matcher with `[^"]`. That way you will not match outside of the string.

## JSON parser approach

Take a look at the following libraries:

- [JSON.simple](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple)
- [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)
- [Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson)

If you don't know the exact structure of the json, I recommend using [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) to remove the keys. But you need to be extra careful not to remove more than you want to. See this example:

maven dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
  <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Java code (minimum Java 15 required):

```java
import com.jayway.jsonpath.DocumentContext;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.Option;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration;

public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        String details = """
            {"queueNumber": "123","UserId":[12,12,34],"cur":[{"objectName":"test","uniqueNumber":"123456"}]}
                """;

        DocumentContext parsedJson = JsonPath.parse(details, 
                // exceptions are thrown when a key is not present. For a simpler demo
                // we suppress all exceptions. Be cautious how to use this implementation
                // in production though!
                Configuration.defaultConfiguration().addOptions(Option.SUPPRESS_EXCEPTIONS));
        
        parsedJson.delete("$..queueNumber");
        parsedJson.delete("$..name");
        parsedJson.delete("$..uniqueNumber");

        System.out.println(parsedJson.jsonString());
    }
}
```

Now, if you are certain about the structure of the given json, you can change the path to the following:

```java
        parsedJson.delete("$.queueNumber");
        parsedJson.delete("$..name");
        parsedJson.delete("$.cur[*].uniqueNumber");
```

You'd only need to adapt the path of the key "name". As it was missing in your example, I don't know where it usually occurs. If you get stuck using the library, check the example section of the readme file, it's well documented: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#path-examples

Comment: This will work for this exact case, but will produce undesired outcome if one of listed fields is not first or last field of corresponding object. Consider [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/30TPg4/1)

Comment: @markalex that is true. I updated my answer with an example code that is safe regarding the order and properties of the json.

Comment: I suggest you splitting this answer it two: regex one, and correct one.

Comment: @markalex No need to. Regex is not the tool for this task.

Comment: @Dragas, while I agree, I still believe this task can be accomplished with regex. Just not in the way how it shown in current answer. Also, I believe answer that contain two opposite approaches should be split, and since author while editing decided to keep regex part, we should result in two answers.

Comment: @markalex what would be the benefit of splitting the answer into two? The main point is to solve the problem and my regex does give a valid solution for the problem in the description. If the problem is more general, then the question must be specified to show all relevant edge cases so that I can adapt my answer. I cannot guess the total requirements...

Comment: @MartindelNecesario, because regex part of your answer warrants a downvote: It lacks any explanation, it will most likely produce undesired outcome (example in question looks like minimized, if object will contain multiple fields with name from regex problem will appear). Also it doesn't explain clear bad decisions of regex in use: redundant groups, redundant `?` in `(\s*)?`, redundant symbol class around comma in the end.

Comment: OTOH, JSON answer is clear, has example and explanation.

Comment: @markalex yes, you are right. I will update my answer when I got time later. Thank you for clarifying the points!

Comment: Hey @markalex, I updated my answer. Please let me know if there is still something unclear

Comment: @MartindelNecesario If the key is an array. the regex is not deleting it. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: @daringfireball for that I strongly recommend the use of a json library. If it must be regex, you could extend the `\w`-part to include all characters that can be part of an array (`[`, `]`, `{`, `}`, `"`, ...). But it likely doesn't work for all cases and it's not manageable to handle further elements inside of an array...

Comment: @MartindelNecesario could you please help me with that? total newbie to regex struggling to figure it out. :)

Comment: take my original regex solution and replace `\w` with `[\w[]{}"]`. This will create a new character class, with which you tell the regex to match any characters that are present in said class. Still, it will get complicated and really bad to handle, when you also have nested arrays (an array that has an array inside etc.). The complicated part will be to tell the regex when to stop. I strongly advice to use a json parser for that task as written in my answer.